# Sequelize sum function always rounding to 4 decimal point

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize v5 and I found that my sum function always return with 4 decimal point, even with manual query (using mysql directly) return with 18 decimal point. I could not found any documentation related to it either.

here my code

```
 let sum = await Deposit.sum("value", {
                where: {
                    state: {
                        [Op.ne] : "failed",
                        [Op.ne] : "cancelled"
                    }
                },
            });
```

and this is Data type for `value` field

```
 value: DataTypes.DECIMAL(36, 18),
```

UPDATE :
I have tested using raw query instead of sum function with sequelize model. It return with full value instead of rounded

```
let query = sequelize.query('select SUM(value) from transactions type = "deposit"');
{ 'SUM(value)': '6870098.867600000001175427' }
```